# A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object?

Tags: php, oop

According to the php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

*A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object*

But doesn't the following example show that you can access a static property from the object `$foo`?

```
class Foo{
    static $my_static = 'foo';
    function staticValue(){
        return self::$my_static;
    }        
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo::$my_static;
```

Comment: Just seems like a vague or misleading statement. I guess they mean you can't do `$this->my_static`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is that you are using the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) :: which always references the class. It doesn't matter if you use $foo or $this or self.

Self is a keyword in PHP that references the current level, but :: can be used on an object to gain reference to the class for that object. self:: is in the same family of keywords as parent::, think of self:: as wanting access to something at the *current* level of an object, and parent:: as wanting access to something *below* the current object.

Therefore, to access something that is defined in the class. PHP created the :: operator. If you just need something from the class that is static, then you can use self inside the class or an object reference outside it.

Comment: i have the same confusion here , where as per given "A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object" how exactly it's works, bcoz we are created object $foo then definitely it's instantiated class then how we are able to access the static variable. it will be very good if any one elaborate on this more.

Comment: @sandipshirsale a static variable is bound to the class declaration. So static variables only have one reference. If you instantiate a class the static variables are not instantiated with it. They remain bound to the class declaration.